# Are va_arg arguments to functions stored in stack or heap memory?

Tags: c++, c++11

Question as titled.  Are variable argument lists stored in stack memory based on their usage, or are they allocated into the heap?

More importantly to where they are stored: Why are they stored in X?

Comment: In the context of _by the standard_, or a _particular implementation_?

Comment: @Eljay By the Standard

Comment: IIRC the standard says very little about va_arg.  If you can use C++11, you can use variadic templates and those are guaranteed to act like normal function parameters (be on the "stack").

Comment: You may want to add `language-lawyer` tag to this question.  That will help get an answer from someone familiar with ISO 14882 that cites chapter-and-verse from the standard, and provide some explanatory interpretation (the standard is written in an exacting exacerbating formal language).

Comment: Implementation-defined.   The standard doesn't even require a stack for arguments.

Comment: There's not even a requirement that an implementation is consistent. It can store integers on the stack, floats on the heap, except for the first three integers and two floats which go in registers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard says nothing about the implementation, only the behaviour of va_arg and associated "macros". They don't even have to be macros.

Variable arguments my use the stack, or registers, as per the "normal" conventions for the compiler. Though I recall that for some compilers in the past, while registers were used for normal functions, stack was /always/ used for var arg functions. The gcc compiler family all seem to agree that the call signatures for var arg functions are exactly the same as properly specified functions, and even K&R default extern function calls follow the same register allocation patterns. This means that some of your var args may be in registers and some may be on the stack if there are too many.

va_arg creates an interface to those arguments. Again the standards don't say how, just the behaviour. It may be possible to implement va_arg completely as a context variable, like an instance of a struct, or it may be necessary for the compiler to reserve additional storage, either by manipulating the stack position, or by using a heap. In these cases it is necessary to call 'va_end' to release those heap or stack reservations: this is always best practice.

Then, of course, you pass your instance of 'va_arg' to a child v-function. Now, the va_arg type parameter acts like a reference to the 'va_arg' instance, though C doesn't have a concept of references generally - the nearest similar concept in function declarations is an array argument, which is implemented as a pointer.

Answer (score 2):

> Are va_arg arguments to functions stored in stack or heap memory?

Maybe.

> ... By the Standard

The standard has nothing to say about the word "stack" except for *stack unwinding* in the context of exceptions, and `<stack>` and `std::stack` in the context of containers.

The standard has nothing to say about the word "heap" except for `is_heap`, `make_heap`, `push_heap` and `pop_heap`.

It doesn't say anything about how `va_arg` *et al* are implemented, either.

> More importantly to where they are stored: Why are they stored in X?

Wherever your implementation and/or ABI chose to store them, they have to be stored *somewhere*, and that's where the implementation and/or ABI chose - possibly for reasons pertinent to your implementation and/or ABI.