# Function arguments memory layout in C (variadic, ...)

Tags: c, arguments, variadic, memory-layout

I'm trying to understand how variadic works in C. I didn't find an answer in Google, so here I am.

When we pass an argument to the function, it creates a copy of a variable and stores it in the stack. To test this statement I wrote this piece of code:

```c
void func(uint32_t a, uint32_t b, uint32_t c) {
  printf("%d == %d\n", a, *(&a - 0));
  printf("%d == %d\n", b, *(&a - 1));
  printf("%d == %d\n", c, *(&a - 2));
}

// somewhere in the code
func(1, 2, 3);
```

The output is:

```
1 == 1
2 == 2
3 == 3
```

So, works, arguments stored in reverse order. Let's rewrite this function with an ellipsis.

```c
void func(uint32_t a, ...) {
  printf("%d\n", *(&a - 0));
  printf("%d\n", *(&a - 1));
  printf("%d\n", *(&a - 2));
}
```

The output is:

```
1
0
0
```

As you can see, the behavior is different. Okay, then, should I look inside the `<stdarg.h>` ([here](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/gcc/ginclude/stdarg.h), for example)? Let's do it!

```c
#define va_start(v,l)   __builtin_va_start(v,l)
#define va_end(v)   __builtin_va_end(v)
#define va_arg(v,l) __builtin_va_arg(v,l)
```

Oh, cool, it's just a macro that calls `__builtin_va_*` functions that defined in... in the [compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22642222/implementation-of-builtin-va-startv-l)?

So, my questions are, -- **Where in the memory do these arguments store? Is it compiler-defined place or not?**

Comment: Maybe helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57164562/are-va-arg-arguments-to-functions-stored-in-stack-or-heap-memory

Comment: How it works depends on your CPU and OS and calling conventions.

Comment: It stored in the stack also. You first code is false too. The language does not define how function arguments has to be stored. Check your example with optimization: https://godbolt.org/z/RSXRbS